# Does the ftp download logic belong in the controller or model of an MVC program

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

I'm writing an application that downloads files from an FTP server and converts them into orders.  The process is download files, place in a pending order folder, process the files in the pending order folder then move them into a completed order folder. Rinse and repeat.

The question is, does the connection and download logic belong in the Model as if it is a data storage or does it belong in the controller as if it is input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It purely belongs to the model of your application.

Read this for some clarity: [Is MVC a design pattern or an architectural pattern?](http://www.swview.org/blog/mvc-design-pattern-or-architectural-pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the article. It's conclusion is MVC can be an architectural pattern or a design pattern but neither of these provides any anecdotal evidence for why the ftp connection lives in the model.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it is correct.   [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc?rq=1) helped more than the link sited in Kamal's comment.

Comment: The purpose I added the link was not because I wanted to provide a detailed explanation about the model. I simply felt that you need to have some understanding about different ways MVC is used as the problem description had no details about a model, view or a controller. In the absence of details about whether you are looking applying MVC to a smaller part or a larger part of your software, my one line answer was to match both. Next line was to hint you that MVC can be applied in two ways - so to improve your clarity about how you will apply it :)